# What is the grammar structure of "arrange to have sent"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, causative-verbs

> Requests that clients send, or arrange **to have sent**, relevant reports from current and previous clinicians.

What is the grammar or usage of *to have sent* in the sentence above?
Thanks

Comment: What have you found so far? This could get pretty complicated before it's all over, but we expect you to have taken a stab at it yourself. See *concatenative verbs* and compare to *infinitives of purpose*.

Comment: It's not a sentence but just part of one, either the VP predicate, or a noun phrase.

Comment: **ᴍᴏᴅᴇʀᴀᴛᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ:** Please do not answer in comments. Write an answer. It can even be an 
incomplete germ of an answer, but please put it in the right place. The
Q&A system cannot cope with answers in comments, and will not mark the question as
answered if you do that. Answering in comments circumvents the very
facilities that allow our Q&A community to police itself and maintain site
quality. If the question requires closing, then please vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parallel construction

> ...requests that clients send, or arrange to have sent, relevant reports ...

abbreviates

> ...requests that clients send relevant reports, or arrange to have relevant reports sent ...